# Search for the most similar string using elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

So, i have elasticsearch index with 5 million strings like: "hello", "how are you", "hi". Just a phrases for my bot.

So, how can I create Java Elasticsearch query to find the most similar strings.

For example: "How are you, Denny?" -> "how are you".

I have tried fuzzy search, but it's not works correct as for me. 
Best implementation i ever seen was: postgres trigrams with Levenshtein distance, but in 5 million strings it works slow.

In general, I need just Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0):

Just using plain Levenshtein distance will be a problem, as it mostly looks at characters and not the whole words and the sequence in which it appears.

For example consider the phrase `THE EYES` and `THEY SEE` , a Levenshtein distance will give a 100% match since they have the same characters, but they mean different things.

Doing trigrams and then doing Levenshtein helps, but again will be error prone where `act` and `cat` will give a false positive match

I found to match words `Soundex` or similar algorithm gives better result.

This is a library I found it useful that uses soundex internally.

https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher

I haven't tried it for 5 million records, but looks like it is a light weight java library, and if configured to run on a large server, should give you the results.